# Typescript Regex pattern boundary in FormControl

Tags: angular, regex, form-control

I have the following custom pattern validator for an Angular FormControl:

```
validateCutOffStartTime(c: UntypedFormControl) {
    const TIME = /\d\d:\d\d/;

    return (TIME.test(c.value)) ? null : {
      validateInput: {
        valid: false
      }
    };
 }
```

So I can only have strings like '10:00'. The problem I still have is the boundary at the end. It still allows me to type in something like '10:00 test'. This should not be possible. How can I adapt that?

Comment: `const TIME = /^\d\d:\d\d$/;`

Comment: @Alex, would suggest you write the solution as **Answer**, but not write it in the question. Refer: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**: `const TIME = /^\d\d:\d\d$/;`